# Need to print the statement inside for loop only once - Perl

Tags: perl, csv, for-loop

I have a nested for loop and I want to print a statement inside the for loop only once. If you see the 4th if statement "if(@arrayTB[$num] ne @arraynew[$num1])", It prints more number of times than required. I am writing to a CSV file and I cannot use a CSV module to do this as my supervisor at work has told me not to. I want the loop to compare all possible Target Branches (TBs) in the file and if it isn't found then print the 3 spaces. Right now it prints 3 spaces each time it makes a comparison. Any suggestions as to how I can fix this?

```
                 for (my $num = 0; $num <= $lengthTB; $num = $num + 2)      
                    {
                        for (my $num1 = 0; $num1 <= $lengthTBresult; $num1++) 
                        {       
                                if(@arrayTB[$num] eq @arrayTBresult[$num1])
                                {
                                    if (@arraybaseline[$num1] eq "null")
                                        {
                                            print OutFile  qq|,@arrayCPnew[$num1],@status[1]|;
                                        }
                                    if (@arraybaseline[$num1] ne "null")
                                        {
                                            print OutFile  qq|,@arrayCPnew[$num1],@status[0]|;
                                        }
                                }
                                if (@arrayTB[$num] ne @arraynew[$num1])                                                                             #if(exists $noTBs{$num})
                                    {
                                        $counter++;
                                        print OutFile qq|,"",""|;
                                    }
                         }

                    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, your `$counter` is set zero/undefined before you enter to this specific for cycle? Then you can achieve it like that:

```
print OutFile qq|,"",""| unless $counter;
$counter++;
```

I don't know reasoning of your boss, but using right module for parsing  CSV would be The Right Solution, anyway

Comment: Yes, my counter is set to zero before entering the for loop. I tried what you suggested, it only prints a space if the first element in the array if it does not match, after that it prints everything that matches to the other array in a line. I want to print a space where ever the elements in the array do not match.

Comment: @Abhishek: sorry, I don't understand exactly, what you mean. Do you get match there in `if` conditional? Does `print` output anything then?  Is it right output? Btw, you sould not use array items with @-sigil, this takes a slice of array and is wrong in most situations

Comment: Yes, I do get a match for the first element in this if statement "if(@arrayTB[$num] ne @arraynew[$num1])" and it prints empty spaces as required but after the first element it does not print empty spaces even if the elements are not equal. Print outputs the statements in the other if condition "if(@arraybaseline[$num1] eq "null")"  and  "if(@arraybaseline[$num1] ne "null")"

Comment: @Abhishek: and what is the value of the `$counter` after the first element? I mean, when you expect printing out, but it does not happen.